# What is the diffrence between `[blah addObject:@"1"];` and `[blah insertObject:@"0" atIndex:0];`?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2

What is the difference between:

```
[blah addObject:@"1"];
```

And

```
[blah insertObject:@"0" atIndex:0];
```

???

I know they're both for a `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`addObject` adds an object at last. `insertObject:atIndex` adds an object at specified index. All objects further to that specified index are shifted one position right.

For example, say you have an array with following objects:

```
A B C D
```

And you add E using `addObject`. Then it will look like:

```
A B C D E
```

Then you insert F at index 2. Then it will look like:

```
A B F C D E
```